# Entity Framework - Expression vs Func

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

Consider this 2 codes:

Using **`Func<T, bool>`**

```
public IQueryable<Blog> GetBlogs(Func<Blog, bool> predicate)
{
   return context.Blogs.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
}
```

Using **`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`**

```
public IQueryable<Blog> GetBlogs(Expression<Func<Blog, bool>> predicate)
{
   return context.Blogs.Where(predicate); // No need of AsQueryable
}
```

So, in the first case, the Entity Framework will always returns all objects from the database, right? So what's the point in calling `AsQueryable`? Does it help anyway? It´s similar to the `Expression` version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it help anyway?

No.

All it does is lie to the caller of the method, in that they *think* that they have an `IQueryable` that will translate any additional operators applied to it to SQL run in the database, when in fact you just have an `IEnumerable` in sheep's clothing.  If you really *want* the operation to be performed in-memory, and not in the DB, then at least be explicit about it an leave the `IEnumerable` typed as an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: If anything, it's a sheep in wolves clothing ;)

Comment: An Microsoft MVP has an article (in MSDN) on how to build repository pattern the "right way" (he even mentions Rowan Miller on his article, saying he was involved in this effort). He uses the `Func` predicate throughout his article and he says that all operations run on the database. I've been fooled for years (since 2014, when the article was published). :(